# How can I use postgresql "inner join" in a ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL query I'm looking mimic in my rails application.

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT *
       FROM event
       INNER  JOIN sensor ON (sensor.sid = event.sid)
       INNER  JOIN iphdr ON (iphdr.cid = event.cid) AND (iphdr.sid = event.sid);
```

This query works great in PostgreSQL.  I'm hoping it will help me achieve less N+1 lookups in my rails app with it but I'm not successfully implementing it.

Here is my attempt:

```
ips_events = Event.joins(:sensor).on(:sensor.sid = :event.sid).joins(:ip_hdr).on(:ip_hdr.cid = :event.cid && :ip_hdr.sid = :event.sid).all.(conditions: ['timestamp >= ?', @ts]).reverse.uniq
```

I'm getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `sid' for :event:Symbol"

Here is the sensor model:

```
class Sensor < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | hostname | interface | filter | detail | encoding | last_cid
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :hostname, :interface, :filter, :detail, :encoding, :last_cid
  self.table_name = 'sensor'

  belongs_to :event,
             :foreign_key => :sid

end
```

The event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | cid | signature | timestamp
  #----------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :signature, :timestamp
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'event'
  has_many :sensors,
           :foreign_key => :sid
  has_many :signatures,
           :foreign_key => :sig_id,
           :primary_key => :signature
  has_many :ip_hdrs,
           :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]
  has_many :tcp_hdrs,
           :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]
  has_many :udp_hdrs,
           :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]
end
```

Here is the ip_hdr model:

```
class IpHdr < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | cid | ip_src | ip_dst | ip_ver | ip_tos | ip_len | ip_id | ip_flags | ip_off | ip_ttl | ip_proto | ip_csum
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :ip_src, :ip_dst, :ip_ver, :ip_tos, :ip_len, :ip_id, :ip_flags, :ip_off,
                  :ip_ttl, :ip_proto, :ip_csum
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'iphdr'
  belongs_to :event,
             :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]
end
```

Comment: You are calling methods on Symbol objects as if they were instances of your ActiveRecord models. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations for more information. You'll need to post the source code for the models you are joining to ensure you have the proper relations defined for the `join` method to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your models declare the associations between `Event` and `Sensor` and `IpHdr`, you can simply write:

```
Event.
  joins(:sensors, :ip_hdrs).
  where("timestamp >= ?", @ts).
  order("event.timestamp desc").
  uniq
```

If you're going to want to access the associated `sensors` and `ip_hdrs` for each of the `events` returned by the query above, you should add `includes` like so:

```
Event.
  joins(:sensors, :ip_hdrs).
  where("timestamp >= ?", @ts).
  order("event.timestamp desc").
  uniq.
  includes(:sensors, :ip_hdrs)
```

Adding `includes` is a hint to ActiveRecord to load the associated models. So the above will happen in three queries: one to load events, one to load sensors, and one to load ip_hdrs. See the [Active Record Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help, not throwing errors now, but not really what I'm looking for. I need to use the primary keys like I'm using in the SQL.(sensor.sid = event.sid), and (iphdr.cid = event.cid) AND (iphdr.sid = event.sid).

Comment: You got me going the right direction, here is what I'm using.`ips_events = Event.includes(:ip_hdrs,:tcp_hdrs,:udp_hdrs,:signatures).all(conditions: ['timestamp >= ?', @ts]).reverse.uniq`

Comment: Cool! Using `all(conditions)` is a bit strange -- I suspect you should be able to use the `where` clause above instead. Also, depending on the number of rows returned, you're probably get better performance using a SQL `order` clause instead of `reverse` as the former will be managed by the database and the latter will happen in Ruby.  But I can understand not wanting to mess with it if it works as is!

Comment: I'm up for less ruby and better performance, thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Good luck. Oh! One more thing: you don't need the `uniq` unless you're using `joins`, as is the use of `joins` that introduces the possibility duplicate `event` models.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue with *Rails* nor *Postgres*, per se. `joins` is the correct method to use for an [`inner join`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) (which is the default `join` in *Postgres*).

The issue here is more of a pure code issue. What the error you mentioned means is that the *object* referred to by the *symbol* `:event` does not have a `sid` method defined for it, and so the `NoMethodError` is raised when you try to call it.

Without the code for the *class* behind `:event`, I can only speculate, but most likely you need to add `sid` as another field to your *data model*, which should then make the method available (assuming you're using, say, *ActiveRecord*, which seems likely, based on the code syntax used above).

Also, your `join` condition for `tcphdr` in your *Ruby* code is different than in the SQL you provided. There's also an extra table, `udphdr`, referenced, that's not in the SQL.

Comment: This isn't correct. The error occurs because the code as written attempts to call the `sid` method on the `:event` _symbol_. The symbol in this context does not represent an ActiveRecord model -- it's just a symbol, so adding `sid` to the data model won't fix the problem. @Greg is correct in his comment above attached to the question.